# Open source online document editor

Tags: document-management

Can somebody tell me some open source projects that implement document management online?

I need to upload document (pdf, docx,fb2), convert it to doc and allow user to edit it online and then convert back to pdf.
Images and formatting should be preserved.

I found teamlab, but it is not free and also I don't need collaborative editing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what your requirements are when you say 'online editing'.

You could use [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.com/) including the [Nuxeo Drive](http://www.nuxeo.com/en/products/drive-desktop-sync) extension, to enable users to edit the files from the remote repository locally (transparent in the sense the user does not take the step of downloading or uploading files), and their changes are then synced to the repository.

The user can edit the .doc file locally using OpenOffice (or MS Word if they have it).

If the requirement is strictly 'online/web only', you could convert the PDF to RTF via an OCR engine such as Tesseract, and then use one of the many WYSIWG inline editors, and connect this to Nuxeo as an edit button using their extension framework.  There is an existing tesseract-ocr extension available at the Nuxeo source repo.